# How do I run Microsoft Explorer 8 plus on Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, wine, playonlinux

First off, you should know I'm a Ubuntu newbie who has become passionate since my strangely low-priced Dell computer showed up with Ubuntu loaded on it and it could do almost everything I need from a computer. But now I've got a problem.

I know, it's like asking how to use a cassette player on your computer, but in South Korea EVERY website is made to work with exclusively on MS Explorer PLUS Active X, which Microsoft finally killed with 9. Hence, I have to use 8, as there are some Korean sites I need to access for searching, banking, etc.

So I see that the way to go is to load PlayOnLinux, but then I it tells me to delete these. Do I really have to do that? Should I just hit "Install Anyway"? Or would that be just asking for trouble?

[image]

Comment: I use old IE for downloading software when the site blocks downloads to non-windows OS's. Do you use PlayOnLinux for anything else?

Comment: Just making sure: You're talking about Microsoft Internet Explorer, or IE? Check out linie: http://code.google.com/p/linie/ To answer your question, those packages are probably safe to remove. If it affects anything, you can post back and we can provide a simple terminal solution.

Comment: Sorry, mis-read it. Its been a hard night. But yes, I would just install anyway.

Comment: Windows Explorer or Internet Explorer?

Comment: Yes, I am talking about MS IE8, and I'll be using it exclusively to access Korean websites that force me to use it to view them. Drives me nuts, but I have no choice.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft actually provides VM images of their software free for developers.

http://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools